# Hikamarket - How to edit the "Vendors' add product" form

Tags: joomla, e-commerce

I'm wondering how can I drop some of fields in the Vendors' add product form. Ex. I'd like to remove "acl", "weight", "currency" ect.
I tried to turn them off in Access Level setting of Hikamarket. But it didn't work. Also, I edited the PHP files but after doing that, the form gives errors that there's no entry to save...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I'd edited Vendor's access level. But didn't get to the result. Now, I edited Product access level in Market > configuration > access level.
Now I got the field I need and have dropped the rest of the fields.